# In Node.js I Can't find the "require('http')" dependacy for using a URL to get image size

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, image-size

I am trying to use the image-size module to get the width of an image via URL. I followed their directions explicitly but can't find the "HTTP" module anywhere (which this seems to require).

I'm fairly new to node.js. Here is my code:

```
    var url = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/url');
    //  var http = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/http'); *** Can't find this to download
    var imgSize = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/image-size/');

    var imgUrl = 'http://my.nintendo.com/static/images/common/ogp/my-nintendo.png';
    var options = url.parse(imgUrl);

    http.get(options, function (response) {
      var chunks = [];
      response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      }).on('end', function() {
        var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        console.log(imgSize(buffer));
      });
    });
```

Here is a link to the package on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must require like this at the top of your file:

```
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');

var sizeOf = require('image-size');
```

You have the module installed in your project node_modules folder?

Comment: Yes, "/usr/lib/node_modules/" is the path to the modules. The issue is since I can't install the 'http' module I don't know how to create a path to it.

Comment: how do you installed node?

Comment: I don't know, our server guy did that. We are on v 5.10.0 and I've used other modules without any issue. This is the first to give me trouble.

Comment: just 
require('http');
comes with nodejs
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http

Comment: Ahh duh. Thanks so much. I never saw your response so sorry for the delay here. It is in fact included and works great. Thank you!